# Show absolute positioned elements in overflow scrolled conteiner

Tags: html, css, scroll, absolute

I have a modal with scrollable list. This list has lots of items, they have absolute positioned elements that should overflow the modal.

How to make absolute positioned elements visible in this case?

```css
.modal {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.list {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content {
  list-style: none;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(46, 20, 20);
  position: relative;
}

.overflow {
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 25%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="content">
      Content area
      <div class="overflow">overflow</div>
    </li>
    <li class="content">
      Content area
      <div class="overflow">overflow</div>
    </li>
    <li class="content">
      Content area
      <div class="overflow">overflow</div>
    </li>
    <li class="content">
      Content area
      <div class="overflow">overflow</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One would assume, that `overflow-x: visible` on the `.list` element would fix it.
BUT nay! CSS automatically assumes if one of both, `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` is set to hidden or scroll, the other one is set to hidden as well.


So in order to make your absolute positioned elements visible again, you'll need another container wrapping your `.list`.
In your example I've simply used the `.modal`, set this to `scroll`, added the `max-height` and removed both from the `.list` element. Also, I've set the modal to 100% width and centered the list.
So now your are scrolling the modal instead of the list and therefore your absolute positioned elements are visible.
Not really a fix for your problem, more like a workaround.

Note: If your absolute positioned elements would go out of the modal, they would disappear again. So keep that in mind.
Note2: In case you don't want apply the scroll to the modal, you can just add another div container inside modal, wrapping the list element.

```css
.modal {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.list {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.content {
  list-style: none;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(46, 20, 20);
  position: relative;
}

.overflow {
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 25%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="content">
      Content area
      <div class="overflow">overflow</div>
    </li>
    <li class="content">
      Content area
      <div class="overflow">overflow</div>
    </li>
    <li class="content">
      Content area
      <div class="overflow">overflow</div>
    </li>
    <li class="content">
      Content area
      <div class="overflow">overflow</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```